# for loop in C: return each processed element

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a linked list, and I want to write a function that will go through each node, and return appropriate elements. Something like this:

```
struct list* returnElements(struct list *head){
     for (; head != NULL ; head=head->next){
         if (head->field1 == "something")
             return head;
     }
```

And then the function that called `returnElements` would have somehow catch each returned node, and do something with it.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: This function will end on the first valid element, you might want to store each valid element on a list or stack etc, and return that instead

Comment: In `returnElements` you can construct a new list, and return this list. You cannot return more than one element with separate returns.

Comment: You're looking to return multiple (pointers to) nodes with each run of `returnElements`? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You could return a collection of node pointers from the function. What type of collection you want is up to you, could simply be an array type of structure, or even another list.

Comment: You should be careful though, that is if you have two lists that reference the same addresses.

Comment: Are you searching for [Implementing linked list with iterator interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369969/implementing-linked-list-with-iterator-interface)? It references to an implementation of [C Iterators](http://www.di-mare.com/adolfo/p/c-iter.htm).

Comment: make a new linked list of that type in the function. then keep 2 copies of the newly created linked lists header. everytime you encounter your element in the original list, add it to the newly created list. finally send the copy we created of the new list in the begining to the main function.

Comment: @hellyale: there is not much sense in iterating a list, creating another with the caller having to iterate _that_.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be easier to do without this function so right inside the function that would call `returnElements` I would make a new variable and set it to type `struct list*` and then traverse that list within the function and if you find a node that you need to use then do something with it so do something like this:

```
struct list *temp = head;
for(; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
    if(strcmp(temp->field1, "something") == 0) {
        //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THIS NODE
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good if he (or her) wants to do their change immediately, but if they are caching the nodes for later access it might not be the best approach.

Comment: @hellyale Thats very true it probably wouldnt be the best approach in that situation. He could create a new linked list with all the nodes he wants to use though and so inside the if statement add the statement that would append each node he wants to the new list. But the way i read the question was that he wanted to do something with it right away

Comment: @JackV I'm processing the nodes immediately. I just wanted to keep all my functions related to the linked list in my linkedlist module, and then have couple of test files that link with the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*you can change the argument type*/
void getElementInNode(void *list){
    /*here you can store the content of the node to a global collection
    or whatever you want here*/
}
struct list* returnElements(struct list* head){
    extern void getElementInNode(void *p);
    struct list* list;

    list = head;
    if (list == NULL){ printf("Empty\n"); }
    while (list != NULL) {
        if (list->field1 == "something"){
            getElementInNode(list);
        }
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```